# How to get the count of no. of keys in a perl 6 %HASH?

Tags: hash, count, raku

Can anyone help to know how to count the no. of keys in a hash, in PERL 6? Looking for something without a manual loop.

Thanks in advance!

**edit**: Tried the following so far but no luck.

```
my %hash =  1 => "one", 2 => <21,22,23>, 3 => "three"  ;

my $count = %hash.keys [ makes it a flat list ]
my $count = %hash.count [no such method]
my $count = keys %hash [provides all the keys but not the count]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In perl5 you can just cast a hash to a scalar and it becomes the count. You can do that in perl6 too:

```
%hash.Int;  
# => 3
+%hash
# => 3
```

Also you have the elems method:

```
%hash.elems;  
# => 3
```

Comment: In Perl 5, you get the buckets if you coerce a hash to scalar.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the IRC Perl 6 Chat community, This is the way to count no. of hash keys, with native/inbuilt functions/methods.

```
%_Host@User> ./h.p6
Count is 3
Count is 3
%_Host@User>
%_Host@User> cat h.p6
#!/usr/bin/perl6

use v6 ;

my %hash = (1 => <1 2 3>, 2 => "ljsf", 3 => "AFDS") ;

say "Count is " ~ +%hash ;
say "Count is " ~ %hash.elems ;
%_Host@User>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'd have a personal preference for seeing %hash.elems in someone else's code that I had to maintain. The +% is easy to miss and can end up with some confusion.

Comment: @MattOates: Yes, possible. We humans are good at missing out on things than not missing out.. hehe

Answer (score 2):

Hashes are [Cool](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Cool), so you can even avoid the [.elems](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/elems) call and just use a hash as a number:

```
my %h = :42a, :72b;
say +%h; # 2
say "We need {42 + %h} spaces to store stuff"; # We need 44 spaces to store stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

**This answer hash been posted before OP edit:**

Your hash initialisation has issues

```
my  %hash = {"1" => "one", "2" => "21,22,23", "3" => "three"} ;
```

should be

```
my  %hash = ("1" => "one", "2" => "21,22,23", "3" => "three") ;
```

Now to answer your actual questions try:

Try this:

```
$count=1;
for %hash.keys.sort -> $key {  #no need to sort though
       # say "$key %hash{$key}";
        $count++;
    }
print "$count\n";
```

Comment: Hi, Is this for Perl5 or Perl6? scalar(keys %hash) doesn't seem to work. Btw.. the hash declaration is just for demonstration purpose, i didn't define it like that. I just took the snip fro dd output to show it here. I have actually defined it like how you have shown, in my real script.

Comment: YOu have to post your code as is here to avoid confusion.

Comment: I have updated my code snippet (hash declaration) but it is clearly mentioned "Perl6".

Comment: Raju, thanks for the loop. I am already aware of counting via a loop but I am looking for equivalent perl6 syntax.

Comment: It would have been really helpful if you had let us know this in the question itself

Comment: Updated the question now.

Comment: @UselessPerson `dd` (which, btw, is a Rakudo compiler built in, not part of the official Perl 6 language) produces output only meant for humans. The output is not meant to be Perl 6 code. What you want for that is `.perl`. This is supposed to produce code that, when evaluated, recreates its invocant. So, for example, `my %hash = :a, :b; say %hash.perl` displays `{:a, :b}` and `%hash = EVAL '{:a, :b}'` would recreate it.

Comment: @raiph, thanks for letting me know that. I was not aware that dd is only Rakudo and not official perl6. Also, you inadvertently answered another question of mine i.e. whats the deal with the :a, :b, :c output.. now I see.

Comment: (p6doc [mentions `dd` being specific to Rakudo](https://docs.perl6.org/programs/01-debugging#index-entry-dd). I think it's just about the only non-standard routine in the docs. But a lot of folk pick it up from examples that don't mention that it's non-standard.)

Comment: Don't need parentheses in the initialization.